# How can spring sftp inbound adaptor ensure whether file is transferred completely

Tags: spring-integration

How can spring sftp inbound adaptor ensure whether file is transferred completely. Is there any check sum mechanism available in spring-integration by default?

Whether spring integration will give any alert/notification if file is partially  transferred to local ?.

Whether spring integration will give any alert/notification if expected file or file format is not in SFTP ?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. No; there is nothing built in; you could write a custom `FileListFilter` (in the `local-filter`) to do that.
2. If you add an error channel to the poller, an exception during file transfer will be sent to it.
3. Not sure what you mean by "format" but the custom filter could check that too. For polls that result in no file there is nothing emitted by default, but you could detect it in a [Smart Poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling).